# How can I create multiple node cassandra cluster on local windows machine using VM

Tags: cassandra, virtual-machine, cluster-computing, cassandra-2.0

I have used CCM to create a multiple node cluster on local machine. But to get a better idea and since I am evaluating Cassandra versus other NoSql technologies, I would like to set up a multiple node Cassandra cluster on my local windows 7 machine using VM or something like that. I have downloaded and installed OVA from below:

http://www.planetcassandra.org/install-cassandra-ova-on-vmware/

But that is a single node. How can I create a cluster with multiple nodes ?

Thanks.

Comment: I posted a detailed answer on how to create a local multi-node Cassandra cluster on Windows 7 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34199571/181406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by creating multiple copies of same ova file in different folders and importing them individually in to VMware player. Once the node has started up, can manipulate config files to create a cluster of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Vagrant to create the VM or with docker containers (although on Windows you'll need a more powerful command line that the one that comes with the OS, like the git shell that comes with Git or Cygwin).

For example, in:

Website: http://joeljacobson.github.io/vagrant-ansible-cassandra/

Github: https://github.com/joeljacobson/vagrant-ansible-cassandra

You can find the instructions (and scripts) to provision a 3 node DSE Cassandra cluster with Opscenter using Ansible and Vagrant.

Or you can also search for other similar projects on Github.